# Error in if() missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed, but there's actually a boolean argument inside

Tags: r, boolean

I have this error in R. I'm working with a database, where my NA values are called "# VALOR N/A", so I did a simple function to see how many of this values I have.

```
    estavencido <- function(a){
  count = 0
  for(i in 2:367){
    if(a[i]== "# VALOR N/D"){
      count = count+1
    }
  }
 return(count)
}
```

But when I use the function, I get the error, and I saw that data[i]=="# VALOR N/D" returns a TRUE/FALSE value, so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: please provide some sample data with `dput()`

Comment: What error do you get? Is it `"# VALOR N/D"` or `"# VALOR N/A"`? If you use a fixed `for(i in 2:367)` you won't get correct counts for another vector, with a different length. Assuming that `a` is your vector, `sum(a == "# VALOR N/D")` will give you the counts you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vector `a` looks like this:

```
a <- c("# VALOR N/A", "A", "B", "# VALOR N/A")
```

Then this will work:

```
estavencido <- function(a){
  count = 0
  for(i in seq_along(a)){
    if(a[i] == "# VALOR N/A"){
      count = count+1
    }
  }
  return(count)
}
estavencido(a)
```

The problem appears when `i` is larger than the length of the vector, in which case `NA` is returned, which is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. Unforseen consequences like this are why you should rather use one of the `seq*` functions in `for` loops.

However the loop you made is not really how you should write this in `R`. This would work a lot better:

```
sum(grepl("# VALOR N/A", a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but maybe something like this:

```
a <- table(a)
a[names(a)=="VALOR N/D"]
```